# How can I reduce the time complexity of an algorithm in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

The following code takes in an integer *t* and then takes in 3 more integers *t* times and returns the maximum number of times you can subtract 1 from two different integers at the same time, whereas the program stops when there is only 1 integer above 0 remaining. I have solved the problem, but I want to reduce the time complexity of the code and I don't know how.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
long long t, r, g, b, arr[1000], count = 0;
bool isMax=true;
cin >> t;

for (long long i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    cin >> r >> g >> b;
    arr[0] = r;
    arr[1] = g;
    arr[2] = b;
    for (long long j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (long long k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            if (arr[k] > arr[k + 1]) {
                long long a = arr[k];
                long long b = arr[k + 1];
                arr[k] = b;
                arr[k + 1] = a;
            }
        }
    }
    count = 0;
    if (arr[2] == 1) {
        cout << 1 << endl;
    } else if (arr[0] + arr[1] <= arr[2]) {
        cout << arr[0] + arr[1] << endl;
    } else {
        while (arr[0] > 0) {
            while (isMax && arr[0] > 0) {
                arr[2]--;
                arr[0]--;
                count++;
                if (arr[2] < arr[1]) {
                    isMax = false;
                }
            }
            while (!isMax && arr[0] > 0) {
                arr[1]--;
                arr[0]--;
                count++;
                if (arr[1] < arr[2]) {
                    isMax = true;
                }
            }
        }
        while (arr[2] > 0 && arr[1] > 0) {
            arr[2]--;
            arr[1]--;
            count++;
        }
        cout << count << endl;
    }
}
}
```

How can I get the same output without using all these loops that increase the time complexity?

Edit: I don't want my code re-written for me, this is homework and all I want are tips and help so I can reduce the time complexity, which I don't know how to do.

Edit 2: In my algorithm, I sort the 3 numbers in ascending order, then I use a while loop to check if the smallest number (s/arr[0]) is > 0. After that, I use two more while loops to alternate between the largest and medium-size numbers (l/arr[2] and m/arr[1] respectively) and decrement from both variables s and l or m (alternating). When s becomes 0, that will mean I can just decrement l and m till one of them equals 0, and then I print the count variable (I increment count every time I decrement two of the variables).

Comment: sounds like homework?

Comment: Instead of showing us code and asking us to rewrite it for you--since this is a question about algorithms and complexity--maybe you can describe your algorithm to us and ask for tips on how to make it more optimal? As it stands this looks like a "write my code for me" homework question.

Comment: I don't want my code to be re-written for me, I want tips on how to reduce the time complexity.

Comment: Think about this: How can you completely remove the innermost loops, where you just increment/decrement counters in each iteration?

Comment: you can reduce complexitiy by using a different algorithm. The same algorithm has a fixed complexity (assuming the implementation isnt messed up)

Comment: Use a better algorithm. Turn *on* your compilers optimizer. Maybe you want https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element

Comment: Sort in *descending* order instead.  Assuming `r ≥ g ≥ b`, think about the different possible cases, `b+g > r`, `b+g = r`, and `b+g < r`. (I believe this can be solved without any loops at all.)

Comment: I agree with @molbdnilo -- the way the question is worded, this should be solvable without any loops.  What's the reason for counting down "manually" in a `while` loop, when you know how far away you are from 0?  It's just a rearrangement and simple math is all that it takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if i understood the problem correctly. But if i did you could optimize the algorithem the following way:

```
int count = 0;
int a = 20, b = 10, c = 21;
sort(a, b, c); // Function that sorts the numbers, so that a is the smallest and c is the largest
count += a;  // count = 10
c -= a;  // a = 10, b = 20, c = 11
if(c < b) {
    float diff = b - c; // diff = 9
    float distribute = diff / 2; // distribute = 4.5
    count += b - ceil(distribute); // count = 25
}
else count += b;
```

You would have to this t times and then sum the count variables, resulting in a complexity of t.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the problem correctly but if you want to know the maximum number of times you can subtract `1` until hitting zero from two elements in a three element set, I believe the answer should be the same as finding the median element of the set. For example, if I have the set

`10 20 30`

The *maximum* amount of times I can subtract 1 is 20, if I always chose to subtract from the subset `{20, 30}`, while the *minimum* would be `10`, if I always choose to subtract from the subset `{10, 20}`.

Hope this helps! (Assuming I didn't totally misunderstand the question ^_^ ")

**`Edit:`**

After the clarifying comment, I believe all you need to do is find the minimum between the sum of the non-maximum elements and the maximum element. Consider the following examples:

If you are given the set `{80, 10, 210}` for example, the answer to your problem is 90, because we can subtract 10 from the subset `{80, 10`}, leaving us with `{70, 0, 210}` where we can further subtract 70 from the subset `{70, 210}`, leaving us with `{0,0,140}`, where we can perform no more operations. **We have performed 80+10 = 90 subtractions by 1** *In this case, max = 210 and min+med = 90*

On the other hand, the consider the set `{2,2,2}`. We can subtract 2 from the subset `{2,2}`, leaving us with `{0,0,2}`, where we can perform no more operations. **In this case, we have performed 2 subtractions by 1** *Max = 2 and min+med = 4*

Last example: consider the set `{2,3,5}`. We can subtract 2 from the subset `{2,3}`, leaving us with `{0,1,5}`, where we can the subtract 1 from the subset `{1,5}`, resulting in `{0,0,4}`, where we can perform no more operations. **In this case, we have performed 2+3=5 subtractions by 1** *Max = 5 and min+med = 5*

If you continue performing examples in this vein, you should be able to convince yourself that the solution is always going to be **min(max, min+median)**.

Comment: You see thats what I thought at first too, but turns out that the maximum for 10 20 30 is 30 because u can subtract from the subset {10, 30} 10 times then the array will be {0, 20, 20} and u can subtract from the subset {20, 20} 20 times, add 20 to 10 and the answer is 30.

Comment: @AlhuthaliHumaid -- Look how you worded your comment.  Does it take loops to figure out the value is 30?  Or just some intuitive thinking?

Comment: @AlhuthaliHumaid I have edited my answer in response to your comment

Comment: @LuisSosa [Test your solution here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20ff0bdd66ba8b7b)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is correct, you can examine exactly what your loops are doing, and look at them more mathematically.

```
if ( arr[2] == 1 ) {
    cout << 1 << endl;
} else if ( arr[0] + arr[1] <= arr[2] ) {
    cout << arr[0] + arr[1] << endl;
} else {
    while ( arr[0] > 0 ) {
        if ( arr[2] > arr[1] ) {
            long long min = std::min( std::min( arr[0], arr[2] ), arr[2] - arr[1] + 1 );
            arr[0] -= min;
            arr[2] -= min;
            count += min;
        } else {
            long long min = std::min( std::min( arr[0], arr[1] ), arr[1] - arr[2] + 1 );
            arr[0] -= min;
            arr[1] -= min;
            count += min;
        }

    }
    count += std::min( arr[2], arr[1] );
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

Assuming your program was correct,t his produces the same results for all inputs I tried.